# Verifying lines don't exceed 79 characters

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, I have my "rulers" setting set to 79 so that I can easily see when I've reached 79 characters. Sometimes when I indent a big block of code or something, I end up with lines that exceed 79 characters and I might not notice that. Is there a way that I can have Sublime Text 2 warn me when any of the open file's lines exceed 79 characters? Even if I have to manually invoke that check, that's fine.

Comment: Are you familiar with python? You're best off creating a simple plugin.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with it. I might try writing a plugin. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Sublime Wrap Plus](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus)? I think this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it out just now and it doesn't seem to handle code too well. [Here](http://pastebin.com/gPW3z9P4) is a PHP file I tested it on.